# getRawValue() without formatting? Symfony

Tags: php, html, symfony1, symfony-1.4

for database i add text with html, for example:

```
<i>test test </i> <strong>test test</strong>
```

in template i use $text->getBody()->getRawValue() and i have formatted text:

*test test* **test test**

if i use only $text->getBody() then i have in template:

```
<i>test test </i> <strong>test test</strong>
```

how can i render text without getRawValue(), but i would like him without html tags strong, i etc. :

```
 test test test test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you after [strip_tags()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)?